# Java equivalent code for az aks get-versions -l eastus

Tags: azure-aks

I need to programmatically list the available aks version in a region using Java API.Is this API exposed in the azure java sdk? If so where?

I tried using azureClient.containerServices().manager().kubernetesClusters().listKubernetesVersions(Region.US_EAST) but this doesn't give me the correct result. This is the result I get is:

- 1.10.12
- 1.10.13
- 1.11.8
- 1.11.9
- 1.12.6
- 1.12.7
- 1.13.4
- 1.13.5
- 1.14.0
- 1.6.9
- 1.9.10
- 1.9.11

I tried the following cli command az aks get-versions -l eastus. This gives me the proper result.

KubernetesVersion    Upgrades 
-------------------  ------------------------ 
1.12.7               None available 
1.12.6               1.12.7 
1.11.9               1.12.6, 1.12.7 
1.11.8               1.11.9, 1.12.6, 1.12.7 
1.10.13              1.11.8, 1.11.9 
1.10.12              1.10.13, 1.11.8, 1.11.9 
1.9.11               1.10.12, 1.10.13 
1.9.10               1.9.11, 1.10.12, 1.10.13

Comment: this just looks like a bug, tbh

Comment: Is there any other way I can get it?

Comment: just query the api directly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the Azure CLI command with a parameter `--debug` like this:

```
az aks get-versions -l eastus -o table --debug
```

Then you will get the details that how does it come true:

[image]

Then you can know that it calls the Azure REST API [Container Service Client - List Orchestrators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/container-service/container%20service%20client/listorchestrators) to get the information. And you can see how to get the same information through Java. Then you can find the [`listOrchestrators(String location, String resourceType)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.management.containerservice.implementation.containerservicesinner.listorchestrators?view=azure-java-stable#com_microsoft_azure_management_containerservice_implementation_ContainerServicesInner_listOrchestrators_String_String_). It does the same thing as Azure CLI command that you execute.

And you can see [how does the function call the Azure REST API in Java in Github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/3e1463aebc74eb7c7d0b7519341f2e268d183ee2/containerservice/resource-manager/v2019_02_01/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/management/containerservice/v2019_02_01/implementation/ContainerServicesInner.java#L95).

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to here.